# How to evaluate classes from files applied globally using Eval - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, eval, fs

Parent script including childscript

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    
    function include(f) {
        eval.apply(global,[fs.readFileSync(f).toString()])
    }
    
    include(__dirname+'/fileToRead.js');

    
    
    
    hi();
    
   let childVar = new child();
```

-------------------------  childScript  ------------------------------

```
  function hi() {
        console.log("hi");
    }
    
    
    class baseObj {
        constructor(){
            console.log("hello")
        }
    
    }
    
    
    class child extends baseObj{
        constructor(){
           super();
    
        }
    }
```

----------------------------result-----------------------------------

```
// the hi function executes
hi

// the instance does not
let childVar = new child();  
^

ReferenceError: child is not defined
```

---------------------Conclusive question---------------------

how do would I get the eval method to globalize the child class as well as the baseObj class using my include method provided.

---------------------------------disclaimer------------------
Disclaimer : I know modules exist and I think they are great , but when you are doing something so large server side its a huge pain to keep track of exports and imports.

Especially since cyclic references exist. Not to mention every single time you create a file you need to add whatever functionality to it with require statements and find the path to those files and then export whatever functionality you are creating in that file to go to other files .

I wish to avoid modules using this method for the most part and make it similar to dealing with client side import statements.

Thanks for the help and have a nice day guys ! :)

Comment: Sorry I'll update it I didn't realize I didn't update that

Answer (score 2):

Your problem boils down to this:

```js
eval('function foo() {}')
console.log(foo) // ok

eval('class bar {}')
console.log(bar) // nope
```

This is because

> Bindings introduced by let, const, or class declarations are always instantiated in a new LexicalEnvironment. (https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-performeval, NOTE)

If you really want to replace the stock `require`, for whatever reason, try using the [VM API](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) (this is what `require` uses under the hood).

Answer (score 1):

If you really-really need this, this is an option, as `class` (unlike `var`) does not create global bindings:

```js
var baseObj = class {
  constructor() {
    console.log("hello")
  }
}

var child = class extends baseObj {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

Comment: Try calling the constructor

Comment: @static660 Sorry, I am not sure I understand the issue.

Comment: I tried this before and it failed to call the constructor of the newly created class instance

Comment: @static660 Well, then you need to provide the minimal code that reproduces the isssue. Because with your simplified example and my fix I get no errors and get the `"hello"` log output.

Comment: Ok maybe I'll try again , it could have to do with something else because I was trying it on my main project and it said failed to call constructor of a non instance or something like that . I'll reproduce and send to you when I'm done k .

Comment: ok figured it out and it works for var , thanks . I will note that you have to use the "global" keyword when instantiating inside parenthesis.